# Tabm (Stata) Equivalent in R

Tags: r, stata

I have a several categorical variables with values from 1-3. I would like to create a table similar to those generated by the tabm feature in Stata which shows me the number of observations for each categorical variable.

In Stata, I would simply write:

```
  tabm Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
```

This is how the table should look (obs=observations):

```
             Value=1    Value=2   Value=3
Variable1      5 obs     10 obs    12 obs
Variable2      2 obs     9 obs     0 obs
Variable3      12 obs    9 obs     3 obs
```

I read some posts about Cross.Table but my version of R won't accept gmodels (R Version 3.4.4).

Comment: `tabm` is not an official Stata command.

Comment: Why not using `?table`? Or perhaps a look into this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each variable has each of the category values and is of equal length we can use rbind and table:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
y <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
z <- c(1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2)

rbind(table(x), table(y), table(z)) #gives us:

      1 2 3
 [1,] 4 2 2
 [2,] 1 3 4
 [3,] 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can apply `table()` whithin a `sapply()`.

***Example***

```
t(sapply(df1[, c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3")], table))
```

***Yielding***

```
> t(sapply(df1[, c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3")], table))
           1  2  3
Variable1 10 17 23
Variable2 20 14 16
Variable3 11 19 20
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(42)
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(5, sample(3, 50, replace = TRUE))), 
                paste0("Variable", 1:5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a `tidyverse` alternative with the same data as above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df1, var, value) %>%
  count(var, value) %>%
  spread(value, n)
```

yielding

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  var         `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
1 Variable1    10    17    23
2 Variable2    20    14    16
3 Variable3    11    19    20
4 Variable4    20    11    19
5 Variable5    19    20    11
```